# How does one configure the vs-code SFTP to work on save when security duo is activated on the remote cluster?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, sftp

I am using sftp with a cluster that has DUO security. Ever since duo security was installed I was unable to push seeminglessly. How can I have my workflow be established as it was?

Error msg:

```
[06-09 10:18:29] [info] Using profile: dev
[06-09 10:18:29] [error] Error: [hal.ncsa.illinois.edu]: All configured authentication methods failed
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/brandomiranda/.vscode/extensions/liximomo.sftp-1.12.9/dist/extension.js:70:107548)
    at Client.emit (events.js:208:15)
    at doNextAuth (/Users/brandomiranda/.vscode/extensions/liximomo.sftp-1.12.9/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:415:12)
    at tryNextAuth (/Users/brandomiranda/.vscode/extensions/liximomo.sftp-1.12.9/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:484:5)
    at SSH2Stream.onUSERAUTH_FAILURE (/Users/brandomiranda/.vscode/extensions/liximomo.sftp-1.12.9/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:597:5)
    at SSH2Stream.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at parsePacket (/Users/brandomiranda/.vscode/extensions/liximomo.sftp-1.12.9/node_modules/ssh2-streams/lib/ssh.js:3772:10)
    at SSH2Stream._transform (/Users/brandomiranda/.vscode/extensions/liximomo.sftp-1.12.9/node_modules/ssh2-streams/lib/ssh.js:694:13)
    at SSH2Stream.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:189:10)
    at SSH2Stream._read (/Users/brandomiranda/.vscode/extensions/liximomo.sftp-1.12.9/node_modules/ssh2-streams/lib/ssh.js:253:15)
    at SSH2Stream.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:177:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:418:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:402:5)
    at SSH2Stream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:302:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:720:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:276:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:210:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17) download /Users/brandomiranda/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/job.sub
```

---

Describe alternatives you've considered:

I've considered using remote-sync but the cluster I have does not allow remote-sync to work.

---

Related links:

- gitissue in the sftp server: [How to use sftp if server uses Duo?](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/780)
- same issue but for pycharm: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/2844389?page=1